# FontForge: how to scale with saving proportions?

Tags: font-forge

I tried to hold the `Alt` or `Shift` or `Ctrl` but anyway I accidently change the aspect ratio of letter when I only need to increase size.

Comment: The [official documentation](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Using_the_Fontforge_Drawing_Tools.html#the-transform-tools) mentions [Shift]: "*The Scale tool lets you freehand rescale an object. **Holding down the Shift key allows you to scale an object while constraining it to the proportional ratio.***"

Comment: Yes but `Shift` do nothing :( I am on Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Same issue here, `Shift` does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ctrl + \`

or

`Element` -> `Transformations` -> `Transform`

[image: fontforge scale with saving proportion]